# FastAPI - Endpoint returns one of enum values

Tags: python, fastapi

I have an app:

```
import enum

from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel


class ClientTypeEnum(enum.Enum):
    UL = 1
    IP = 2
    FL = 3


class Request(BaseModel):
    text: str


app = FastAPI()


@app.post('/classify')
def classify(request: Request):
    return
```

How can I realize that in swagger one could see that response possible values are values of **ClientTypeEnum**?

Comment: See [response model](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/response-model/)

Answer (score 2):

Update the API endpoint with a response model

```
@app.post('/classify', response_model=ClientTypeEnum)
def classify(request: Request):
    return
```